# There is any way to show pdf in a received email like embedded pdf?

Tags: php, email, pdf, phpmailer

Im trying to find some information about show pdf in emails like in a embedded way, for the user dont need to click to open pdf to can see! I want that the pdf is already open when the user open the received email.
Im trying to do this for a newsletter that is in pdf format.

Do you know how this can be done?Which plugin technology?

Thank you,

Below there is my code to send email but

```
$date = date('d/m/Y H:i');   
$msg = " 

There is our newsletter:
(here I want to show the pdf)
<br />
Best regards
<br />
Send in: $date

";

$for= 'test@hotmail.com';
$subject= 'Newsletter';
$headers = "From: $for\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n\n";
mail($email,$subject,$msg,$headers);
```

Comment: No. Not with any degree of reliability, at least. Your best bet is to send the PDF as an attachment and let the user's mail client handle it. Most modern desktop, mobile clients, as well as many webmail solutions, do this just fine. It's worth noting that this is not just an issue of functionality, but also of security. No programmer in their right mind would write code to automatically open a file format as frequently exploited as a PDF.

Comment: Maybe you can, maybe you cannot, it will depend on what PDF reader the user has and what is he using to view this e-mail. Even pure HTML is often restricted in e-mail body due to numerous reasons. I recommend you give up this idea.

Comment: You are trying to outsmart the users. Don't. It is their choice how they want to view their messages, isn't it?

Comment: why not just send a nicely formatted html email, i hate attachments when the contents could of just been in the email

Comment: Thanks for your answers, this work must be done using PDF, I have to be able to send an email that corresponds to a newsletter in PDF format, so I'm looking for the best solution

Comment: as the writer of a  newsletter sending web application - you cant.

Comment: Sorry Dagon but I didnt understood your answer, I cant send pdf in html email?

Comment: you can send it as an attachment just fine, but you cant send it in a way that it is automatically opened.

Comment: Ah ok thank you for your clarification. And do you know if its possible send a link in my html body that when the user click it open the pdf?

Comment: link to web site hosting pdf, then it would depend on the users settings if it opened the pdf in browser or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you send an email with a PDF attachment that the receiving email client knows how to display (e.g. Apple Mail), it will display it. You have no control other than formatting the message correctly so that the client can choose.

To do this you can use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), example code [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mail.phps).

Aside from that I'd say don't do it - either format your newsletter as HTML, or provide a prettified link to the PDF online.